# Adding a prefix to section title

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script

The default for numbering sections, subsections, and subsubsections is:

```
1. Section

1.1. Subsection

1.1.1. Subsubsection
```

For one particular project I want them to number like this:

```
1.1. Section

1.1.1 Subsection

1.1.1.1. Subsubsection
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What document class are you using?

Comment: Then what should the first number in “1.1 Section” refer to? Is it fixed?

Comment: Yes, it's a chapter number.  I'm making a preprint of my own chapter  out of an edited book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{1.\arabic{section}}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Well, yes, of course, that works, but now the question title is too general for the problem at hand and the answer. Care to edit that?

Comment: Actually, I just had an idea for a better title and felt free to edit it.

Comment: By the way, in case anyone is interested, the same solution egreg gave can easily be intuitively extended to the other numbered items.  For example:  \renewcommand{\thesection}{2.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{2.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{2.\arabic{table}}